# how to extract titles from a text file and use those titles to open other files and search for patterns

Tags: regex, perl, file, loops

I am trying to figure out a Perl program that reads a text file containing file names, opens each of those files and searches them for a regular expression (eg GGggG).

I am reasoning that first I need to read the file and save everything into an array.

Then `foreach` element of the array, `open` the corresponding file and search within it.

Can someone please help?

This code works (gratia Chankey Pathak) for lines containing only one title thus not needing any processing:

```
 my $filename = 'names.txt';
    open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        chomp $_;
        my $file_contents;
        {
            open (my $fh, '<', $_) or die $!;

            my $file_contents = '';
               while (<$fh>) {
               $file_contents .= $_;
        print "Matched!" if $file_contents =~ /gggggg/i;
}
}
}
```

But what if the name file is full of names (few/line) separated only by \t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be like below to solve the problem.

```
my $filename = 'names.txt';
open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;

# assuming each line contains file name
while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp $_;
    my $file_contents;
    {
        open (my $fh, '<', $_) or die $!;
        local $/ = undef;
        $file_contents = <$fh>;
        close $fh;
    }
    print "Matched!" if $file_contents =~ /GGGGG/;
}
```

See:

- [Open and read from text files](http://perlmaven.com/open-and-read-from-files)
- [Regex in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [Loops in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control)